# $X^* X X^\top = X^\top \overline{X} X^\top$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I was doing matrix multiplication and noticed the following,

$$
X^* X X^\top = X^\top \overline{X} X^\top
$$
where $X,X^\top,X^*$, is a complex N x N matrix, its real transpose and its hermitian transpose respectively.  Why is this true?  I was able to reason that it can only be true if

$$
X^* X=\overline{(X^* X)}=X^\top \overline{X}
$$
since $X^*=\overline{X^\top}$.
So then we indeed have
$$
X^* X X^\top = X^\top \overline{X} X^\top
$$
My question is, why then is
$$
X^* X = \overline{X^* X}?
$$
Now If $z\equiv X^* X$, and $z$ was a scalar, $z=\overline{z}$   implies $z\in \mathbb{R}$.  Does this hold for matrices also?  Is it then true that $X^* X \in M_{N}(\mathbb{R})$? If so , can we prove that in general
$$
X^* X \in  M_{N}(\mathbb{R})?
$$ or was this just an accidental case based on the matrices I was working with? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why then is $X^\ast X=\overline{X^\ast X}$?

It is not. Counterexample:
$$
X=\pmatrix{1&i\\ 0&0},\ X^\ast X=\pmatrix{1&i\\ -i&1}\notin M_2(\mathbb R).
$$

Comment: Okay so I realize there is a counter example thanks! So my case was just accidental based on what $X$ was ?

Comment: @Integrals Whether it's accidental or there's a deeper reason depend on what exact examples of $X$ you have tried.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what I was looking for.